# Does BrowserWindow.fromId return windows that have been destroyed?

Tags: electron

When I create a `BrowserWindow` in Electron and do operations on it, I've been habitually checking if the window is destroyed:

```
const window = new BrowserWindow(opts);
setMyWindow(window);

// ... later
const window = getMyWindow();
if (window && !window.isDestroyed()) {
    // do something on the window
}
```

The reasoning is that if the user closes the window, the `window` variable would still be set since I haven't explicitly nulled it out, but the actual Window that my `BrowserWindow` wraps would be invalid, and that is presumably what `isDestroyed()` is checking.

Are there times when it is not necessary to do the check?

Specifically, does `BrowserWindow.fromId(windowId);` return windows that are destroyed? If `fromId` gives me a window, can I safely not check `isDestroyed()`, or do I still need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick test and if you close the `BrowserWindow` by clicking the X or by calling `window.close()`, `BrowserWindow.fromId(myWindowId)` returns `null`.

So, if you fetch the window via `BrowserWindow.fromId`, you do not need to check if it's destroyed. If you don't use `fromId` and simply store and get the window from a variable, then you should still check `isDestroyed()`.

That being said, I'm not sure if there are other cases where calling `isDestroyed()` is redundant.

Comment: good to know that it returns `null`! ;) However, "then you should still check isDestroyed()" is not true. An other (IMO better) habit is to set window reference to `null` in 'closed' callback. That way you just `if (window) { ... }`

Comment: @pergy Well, I would agree. I was thinking if you don't take those precautions then you might have a situation where `window` is set, but `isDestroyed()` is true. I hope clearing the window reference in the closed callback will handle all such cases (where `isDestroyed()` is true)